# Is encoding ASCII character as multiple bytes legal in UTF-8?

Tags: encoding, utf-8

In UTF-8, code points >127 encoded with multiple bytes. For example, character `U+041F (100'0001'1111)` encoded as:

```
1101'0000 1001'1111
^^^       ^^
```

Marked bits determine leading and trailing bytes, other bits are actual bits of the code point.

But can we encode code point `1` as

```
1100'0000 1000'0001
```

Of course, it is redundant, but is it legal in UTF-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overlong UTF-8 sequences are not considered valid UTF-8 representations of a code point.  A UTF-8 decoder must reject overlong sequences.

Wikipedia citation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Overlong_encodings

Original RFC 2279 specification: https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2279.txt